# Nvidia 390/340 drivers problem on hybrid graphics

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics, hybrid-graphics

I have a Nvidia hybrid graphics chipset Geforce 540M and currently I'm using, as suggested, the 390 driver for Ubuntu 64-bit on a fresh Xubuntu 20.04 LTS 64-bit system.

But I've even tried 340.

I've tried to install them via many ways, like "additional drivers" or "apt" or via manual download/install from Nvidia site.

From Gnome, I've "downgraded" my system to Mate first and lastly to XCFE trying to get rid of the problem, but there is no improved performance or thermal problems.

I am in the situation that even 2 tabs of a browser can make my system stop due to overheating.

The worst thing - and frustrating to me - is that Windows 10 works perfectly, no reboot and no freeze, no thermal issue, even with many programs opens. So, I can say that is not about a fan/dust/paste problem.

How to solve this problem without buying a new laptop, as the market suggest and several post on some forums as well.

> [image: Blockquote]

After selection "on demand" and reboot the system the fan is still on.
And if I run nvidia-settings:

> sudo nvidia-settings "ERROR: Unable to load info from any available
> system (nvidia-settings:2557): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 13:34:18.908:
> g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
> ** Message: 13:34:18.914: PRIME: Requires offloading
> ** Message: 13:34:18.914: PRIME: is it supported? yes
> ** Message: 13:34:18.956: PRIME: Usage: /usr/bin/prime-select nvidia|intel|on-demand|query
> ** Message: 13:34:18.956: PRIME: on-demand mode: "1"
> ** Message: 13:34:18.956: PRIME: is "on-demand" mode supported? yes"

and from the main window all infos disappear:
[image]

If I select Intel, when i reboot ive this error:

> sudo nvidia-settings
>
> ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded
>
> ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
>
> (nvidia-settings:2418): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 14:00:44.099:
> g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
> ** Message: 14:00:44.106: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
> ** Message: 14:00:44.106: PRIME: is it supported? no

[image]

Comment: Please check the edit. I've noticed English isn't your native language and the text was terrible to follow. Also removed one sentence because unneeded and untrue.

Comment: **Which graphics are you using in Ubuntu? Please check at Nvidia X Server Settings**. If Nvidia (high performance profile) then you CAN'T conclude there aren't hardware issues. On Windows hybrid graphics work on-demand. It means that unless running specific software like games or 3D rendering the system enables the integrated GPU (likely Intel) and uses it at all times so, depending on what you're doing in Windows, the discrete Nvidia may not be working at all. If that's the one with a problem you wouldn't notice it. Please check and give feedback.

Comment: @ChanganAuto is setted to performance mode, and a switch to "on demand" do not save me from termal! Thanks a lot for the edit!!!! As I said the problem on ubuntu comes with even 2 tabs of a browser scrolled twice! On windows I can watch a movie on streaming or even have an ide open while im browsing web, impossible from ubuntu!!! I'll update my post with X server settings!

Comment: **Change it to the Intel (power saving), not "on demand" or "high performance" and test again**. Intel only is what you're using in Windows for "watching a movie, streaming or local" and 90% or something of anything else running at the same time. And although *thermal* is acceptable, not "termal", people will understand a lot better if you say overheating instead.

Comment: apologize for my bad bad eng, ive read a lot about "termal" in other post so ive started to use this therm too! Is it normal that after selection "on demand" is still the fan working at the startup? and all infos disappear from the window of "prima-profile"? I'll add them on the main post!

Comment: "On demand" seldom works as intended and certainly not with old chipsets.

Comment: if i select intel, when i run again nvidia-settings, an error comes "ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded"

Comment: That should be the least of your concerns right now. Please test it with Intel only with the some software you were using in Windows. Does it behave differently? Noticeable differences aren't to be expected which proves the initial hypotheses.

Comment: no, fans still running a high rate

Comment: Fans aren't that relevant (and it could be that it still needs to cool down from before). Is it stopping like before? That's the question. Keep using it doing the things the triggered the problem before and compare.

Comment: ok its seems better.... there is no benchmark where i can test it? now ive 7 browser tabs open, visual studio open and a video runnings on streaming

Comment: No need for artificial benchmarks when the real world usage just confirmed the hypotheses. Unfortunately the objective material conditions, rather than the market or online opinions, that suggest you need a new laptop. That one is repairable if you manage to find the part (very unlikely) but the cost (parts+service) for such old hardware that can fail the same or other part anytime now, makes said decision irrational.

Comment: what is broken then? a reply like this is very welcome as user, but as linux user is like a nightmare... as we run linux against wasting of resource, and as some very old laptop are still in use, why mine needs to be upgrade? thanks a lot for your time!!!

Comment: What's broken is the Geforce 540M. If by effectively disabling the dGPU it works for your needs then keep it until it breaks for good. You may even have the chance to disable it in UEFI ("BIOS") and avoid messing with drivers (not all have this feature). But then the obvious question, if it's enough for your needs like this why did you bought it with an additional Nvidia GPU? Certainly many similar models with Intel only were available at the time, as they're available now and anything that you can buy now even with only iGPU is far superior than yours even with a working dGPU.